# How to access map in velocity template file by using Variable Declaration

Tags: java, templates, velocity

I have created map which contains the postal address which is finally pass to homeAddress map .See the below code

```
        Map map1 = new HashMap();
        map1.put("address", "address1 trinity");
        map1.put("address2", "addressmg road");
        map1.put("city", "bangalore");
        map1.put("state", "karnataka");

        Map map2 = new HashMap();
        map2.put("postal_address",map1);

        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        context.put("homeAddress",map2);
```

Template code:

```
    Variable Declaration:
    #set ($PostalAddress_Address2 ="address2")
    #set ($PostalAddress_City ="city")
    #set ($PostalAddress_State ="state")
    Iterating the Map:
    #set($tocList=${homeAddress.postal_address})
    $tocList.get($PostalAddress_Address2)
    $tocList.get($PostalAddress_State)
    $tocList.get($PostalAddress_City)
```

The above code works fine.But when i replace the  variable Declaration for postal_address_main as postal_address then its not working

```
   #set ($postal_address_main ="postal_address")
    #set($tocList=${homeAddress.postal_address_main })
```

Any suggestion on this? how to replace the Variable declaration while fetching the value from map?

Comment: Possible answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344341/reference-a-map-by-name-within-velocity-template?rq=1

Comment: thanks Jira for this clue..but i didnt get where to write the method in my case

Comment: thanks Jira i am able to fix the above issue

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the above issue,

```
 #set ($postal_address_main ="postal_address")
 #set($tocList=$homeAddress.get($postal_address_main))
```

first take the map(`$homeAddress`) and from map get the actual value by replacing the VLT(`$postal_address_main`).